# SciChart wpf text annotation with html rendering

Tags: c#, html, text, scichart

I want to show a simple little table of text in a SciChart WPF graph. In java the methods to create tooltips and labels support simple html rendering, e.g. I could define `text="<html><body>line1<br>line2</body></html>"` and it would show two lines of text. Is something similar possible with a SciChart TextAnnotation?

Comment: Hello. Is this referring to SciChart.WPF, or SciChart.Android? It's not clear from the question

Comment: fixed. @Dr.ABT thanks for the hint